# How to Fill the Gap Between Camera Clip Plane And Skybox?

Tags: unity

[image]

I'm talking about the brown-greyish area i marked with blue. How can i fill it with *something* that does fit the environment?

I'm looking for a solution like [this plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/31861).

Comment: Looks like that plugin is just a tessellated plane mesh with heightmap sampling in the vertex shader. But you can use a big handmade mesh as well.

Comment: You can also use matte painting as skybox instead of simple one

Comment: @snake5 I tried to add a huge plane under terrain but, i always end up with that greyish ugly hole in my horizon. Because even though i make plane bigger, camera clips it down, so nothing changes.

Comment: A simple plane obviously won't work. It must be deformed to look like a huge terrain, covering the horizon. You can do that either in the vertex shader or in a modelling app. Also, increase the far plane distance of the camera. Or render it with another long-range camera, before the main scene, if increasing the far plane creates Z-fighting.

Comment: @snake5 Why would i add huge mountains around my scene? I mean, other games just show planes going up to horizon, isn't there a way to achieve it? Like an ocean or plateau going up to horizon.